# How can I add pan and zoom controls to a Processing.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, zooming, processing, pan

I can draw shapes on a canvas. Now I'd like to let users pan and zoom in and out using keyboard controls.

Comment: This post may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339533/transform-screen-coordinates-to-model-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable to keep track of user feedback for zoom and pan, which you use as arguments to the `translate()`(pan) and `scale()`(zoom) functions.

It might help to have a look how [Proessing.js fits](http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/jsQuickStart#externalsproperty) with js/html/css.

HTH

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can scale and blot things to a canvas, I can buffer with a PGraphic and blot that, but when I scale the PGraphic and blot it, nothing shows up on the canvas.