# Transform screen coordinates to model coordinates

Tags: mouse, scale, processing, processing.js

I've got some sort of newbie question.

In my application (processingjs) i use scale() and translate() to allow the user to zoom and scroll through the scene. As long as i keep the scale set to 1.0 i've got no issues. BUT whenever i use the scale (i.e. scale(0.5)) i'm lost...

I need the mouseX and mouseY translated to the scene coordinates, which i use to determine the mouseOver state of the object I draw on the scene.

Can anybody help me how to translate these coordinates?
Thanks in advance!
/Richard

Comment: Please post your code! This might clarify your problem; or we can at least reproduce your problem. You say that you're lost. Lost how? what happens?

Comment: This post may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470819/transform-from-relative-to-world-space-in-processing

Comment: Thanks! It is... I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for me this required a code modification.  I'll look at submitting this to the Processing.JS code repository at some point, but here's what I did.

First, you'll want to use modelX() and modelY() to get the coordinates of the mouse in world view.  That will look like this:

```
float model_x = modelX(mouseX, mouseY);
float model_y = modelY(mouseX, mouseY);
```

Unfortunately Processing.JS doesn't seem to calculate the modelX() and modelY() values correctly in a 2D environment.  To correct that I changed the functions to be as follows.  Note the test for mv.length == 16 and the section at the end for 2D:

```
p.modelX = function(x, y, z) {
  var mv = modelView.array();
  if (mv.length == 16) {
    var ci = cameraInv.array();
    var ax = mv[0] * x + mv[1] * y + mv[2] * z + mv[3];
    var ay = mv[4] * x + mv[5] * y + mv[6] * z + mv[7];
    var az = mv[8] * x + mv[9] * y + mv[10] * z + mv[11];
    var aw = mv[12] * x + mv[13] * y + mv[14] * z + mv[15];
    var ox = 0, ow = 0;
    var ox = ci[0] * ax + ci[1] * ay + ci[2] * az + ci[3] * aw;
    var ow = ci[12] * ax + ci[13] * ay + ci[14] * az + ci[15] * aw;
    return ow !== 0 ? ox / ow : ox
  }
  // We assume that we're in 2D
  var mvi = modelView.get();
  // NOTE that the modelViewInv doesn't seem to be correct in this case, so
  // having to re-derive the inverse
  mvi.invert();
  return mvi.multX(x, y);
};
p.modelY = function(x, y, z) {
  var mv = modelView.array();
  if (mv.length == 16) {
    var ci = cameraInv.array();
    var ax = mv[0] * x + mv[1] * y + mv[2] * z + mv[3];
    var ay = mv[4] * x + mv[5] * y + mv[6] * z + mv[7];
    var az = mv[8] * x + mv[9] * y + mv[10] * z + mv[11];
    var aw = mv[12] * x + mv[13] * y + mv[14] * z + mv[15];
    var oy = ci[4] * ax + ci[5] * ay + ci[6] * az + ci[7] * aw;
    var ow = ci[12] * ax + ci[13] * ay + ci[14] * az + ci[15] * aw;
    return ow !== 0 ? oy / ow : oy
  }
  // We assume that we're in 2D
  var mvi = modelView.get();
  // NOTE that the modelViewInv doesn't seem to be correct in this case, so
  // having to re-derive the inverse
  mvi.invert();
  return mvi.multY(x, y);
};
```

I hope that helps someone else who is having this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.
Looks like something I could not have figured out myself!

Comment: Hi orionr! I've replaced the methods within the processing.js file. But this does not seem to fix the issue. Whenever i call the methods modelX(x,y) and modelY(x,y) the returnvalue eventually reaches NaN (every iteration the number gets smaller and smaller). Some variable is adjusted and remembered within processing it seems. Any clues?

Comment: Hi Richard - I haven't seen that issue myself and have a sample where the user scrolls and zooms through a map-like world.  Are you always getting the mouseX and mouseY values fresh each time you call modelX() and modelY()? I noticed you said modelX(x,y) up there so wondering if maybe you are modifying the mouseX and mouseY values before passing it in?  Feel free to paste some code in and we can take a look.

Comment: Do you know if Processing has already a solution for this? It weird having to use a hack. :/ But, it seems to do want I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another method?

For example, assume that you are in a 2D environment, you can "map" all the frame in a sort of matrix.
Something like this:

```
int fWidth = 30;
int fHeight = 20;
float objWidth = 10;
float objHeight = 10;

void setup(){
  fWidth = 30;
  fHeight = 20;
  objWidth = 10;
  objHeight = 10;
  size(fWidth * objWidth, fHeight * objHeight);
}
```

In this case you will have a 300*200 frame, but divided in 30*20 sections.
This allows you to move in somewhat ordered way your objects.

When you draw an object you have to give his sizes, so you can use `objWidth` and `objHeight`.

Here's the deal: you can make a "zoom-method" that edit the value of the object sizes.
In this way you drew a smaller/bigger object without editing any frame property.

This is a simple example because of your inaccurate question.
You can do it [in more complex ways], in a 3D environment too.